# How can I let a code run permanent in the background, which waits for an input ? (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net

I want to program a round based rpg like game in visual basic.
For that I want to make it possible, to show a picture of the current selected unit in the right bottom corner and add some information about the heal points and some other stats.
So I want to make a program part, which permanently asks, which of the units is selected and based on that let a other program part running, which changes the picture and the information about hp and this stuff, matching to the current unit.

But I am not able to run a program which runs in the background and doesn't freezes the main program while running (may I need a background worker ?)
Also I am not very sure, what for a program type I need to used for this (like a sub or something).
I don't know other types than sub's in vb, but I could derive it from my knowledge of java programming (functions and objects).

I know this is a bit much to ask, but I need to know, which program type I need to use and how I can let it run permanent in the background + how to transfer some information between these parts.

Would be nice, if someone could help me and explain a bit instead of just saying something like: you need a background worker use this link xy.

I tried to use a variable, which becomes a different number, when a other unit is clicked, unfortunately you cant see much of my code right now, since for this form, I didn't created much more than the graphical interface.

```
Public Class FormBattlescreen
    Dim marked As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Formsounds_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        FormMainCampagne.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OwnSoldier1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OwnSoldier1.Click
        marked = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub OwnSoldier2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OwnSoldier2.Click
        marked = 2
    End Sub

    Private Sub OwnSoldier3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OwnSoldier3.Click
        marked = 3
    End Sub

    Private Sub EnemyOfficer1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnemyOfficer1.Click
        marked = 4
    End Sub

    Private Sub RunGame()
        Select Case marked
            Case 0 'nothing is selected//at the beginning
            Case 1
                PictureBoxStats.Image = My.Resources.Soldier2
            Case 2
            Case 3
            Case 4
        End Select

    End Sub

End Class
```

Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking correctly, it seems to be a natural fit for the typical Windows style of programming.  The part that runs in the background is the standard Windows message loop; this is already provided for you by the framework, and you don't need to worry about it.  Then, you can add event handlers to respond to the user's actions to change the state of the program.  In your example, instead of setting the image in `RunGame`, you should do it in `OwnSoldier2_Click`.

Comment: Whops, you are right, i can do it this way, what was up with my mind ?
But still, i need something running in the background and check, wich unit was clicked last, since i want to add some action buttons like "attack" or "defend" and then do a action based on the combination of clicked button and the last clicked unit. But thanks for this hint right for now.

Comment: You can maintain global state to track things like the active unit.  In VB, this might be done through `Shared` variables or through a `Public` field or property in a Module.